# Export multiple Highchart as Zip file to my project directory

Tags: php, jquery, highcharts

- I have successfully created total 4 different charts in one my page.
- I have one button "Download Selected Chart" and on click of this button **I need to create one ZIP file with selected chart PDF, Means if I select three charts then create a ZIP with three charts PDF.**
- Highchair provides functionality to download chart as PDF, SVG, PNG etc but I amn't able to do for multiple selected charts.
- I check Highchart export server document -
  http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server but I don't understand how to use this.

please help me if anyone has an idea, how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

An example solution to this would be:

1. Create your charts

   ```
   var options1 = { 
       // ...
   };
   $('#chart1').highcharts(options1);
   ```
2. Ask the Highcharts export server to generate an image of the chart

   ```
   var exportUrl = 'http://export.highcharts.com/';
   var d1 = $.ajax({
       url: exportUrl,
       // ...
   });
   ```
3. Fetch the contents of the generated image

   ```
   $.when(d1).done(function(v1) {
       var p1 = new JSZip.external.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(exportUrl + v1[0], function(err, data) {
               // ...
           });
       });
       // ...
   ```
4. Use JSZip to construct and save the ZIP file with the contents of the generated images

   ```
       // ...
       Promise.all([p1]).then(function(values) {
           var zip = new JSZip();
           zip.file("chart1.png", values[0], {binary:true});
           zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
           .then(function(content) {
               saveAs(content, "charts.zip");
           });
       });
   });
   ```

You can see [this (very scrappy) JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/c9hvvsoL/) of how you could get the ZIP file. The steps are as described above, but not connected to any button and instead executed immediately upon entering the site.

Comment: Thank u @halvorStrand for your soluction. your answer give me an idea about how i need to go ahead but now i also want csv file in Zip archive. so i think i need to use PHP anyhow. do u have any idea ?

Comment: You want to get the chart data as CSV, and add it to the ZIP? Then I'd still use JSZip, but maybe in combination with a Highcharts plugin like [Export-CSV](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) where you can get the CSV.

Comment: yes. On single button click i want to create PDF and CSV for selected chart and add all file(csv and pdf) in one ZIp.

Answer (score 1):

Here i post my solution that is work for me.

1. On Button click, get svg image using High chart export server.

   ```
        // get selected checkbox
        $('.selected_checkbox').each(function( index ){ 
            var obj = {},chart;
            chart = $('#each_chart').highcharts();
            obj.svg = chart.getSVG();
            obj.type = 'image/png';
            obj.async = true;
            obj.id = chart_id; 
           // ajax call for svg 
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: url,// u need to save svg in your folder
                   data: obj, 
                   success: function(data)
                   { 
                    // redirect to php function and create zip 
                    window.location = 'php function call';
                   }
             )}
   ```
2. Ajax Function call to create SVG..

   ```
         ini_set('magic_quotes_gpc', 'off');
       $type = $_POST['type'];
       $svg = (string) $_POST['svg'];
       $filename = 'name';
       $id = $_POST['id'];

   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
           $svg = stripslashes($svg);  
   }
   // check for malicious attack in SVG
   if(strpos($svg,"<!ENTITY") !== false || strpos($svg,"<!DOCTYPE") !== false){
           exit("the posted SVG could contain code for a malicious attack");
   } 

   $tempName = $filename.'_'.$id;
   // allow no other than predefined types
   if ($type == 'image/png') {
           $typeString = '-m image/png';
           $ext = 'png';

   } elseif ($type == 'image/jpeg') {
           $typeString = '-m image/jpeg';
           $ext = 'jpg';
   } elseif ($type == 'application/pdf') {
           $typeString = '-m application/pdf';
           $ext = 'pdf';
   } elseif ($type == 'image/svg+xml') {
           $ext = 'svg';
   } else { // prevent fallthrough from global variables
           $ext = 'txt';
   }


      $outfile = APPPATH."tempp/$tempName.$ext";
      if (!file_put_contents(APPPATH."tempp/$tempName.svg", $svg)) { 
       die("Couldn't create temporary file.");  
   }}
   ```
3. Ajax Success function redirect code..
    Here you need to read directory files and create PDF from SVG.
    After add each PDF to ZIP.

**This is Example solution.You have to change code as per your requirement**